# How to display alert if request is longer than 30 sec in angularJs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Sometimes it takes too long for a request, I want to display some alert or toastr when this happens. Any idea how to catch the request time? Thanks in advance

Comment: if the request uses a Promise you can always use `Promise.race`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a promise `$q`, since promises can only be resolved once, and cannot be resolved after having been rejected. In this example, use the input to specify the wait time in seconds, before the request is completed. An alert is shown after 5 seconds if the request has not completed by then.

```js
angular.module("app", [])
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope, $timeout, $q) {
    $scope.wait = 0;

    $scope.request = function() {
      const timer = $q.defer();
      
      timer
        .promise
        .then(function(value) {
          alert(value);
        })
        // do nothing
        .catch(() => {});
      
      $timeout(function() {
        timer.resolve("Request takes too long");
      }, 5000);
      
      $timeout(function() {
        // Here your request resolves successfully
        console.log("Resolving request");
        timer.reject();
      }, $scope.wait * 1000);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input type="number" ng-model="wait">
  <button ng-click="request()">Click</button>
</div>
```